# help adding a field to my sql proc result

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2005, pivot

I have the SQL proc below that I am trying to add a SRS start date field to the result set of the proc below. I want to add a field for SRS_StartDate. The field should be defined as such: `coalesce(projectMilestone.startDate, releaseschedual.startDate) as SRS_StartDate` - but only for CID=37 as this is the cid for SRS

I am attaching my sample sql code below  for my current proc and [a file of table structure and data as well](https://fileshare.egnyte.com/h-s/20110121/ffbe647010ee4434).

you can test with these projectIDs as the excel file has data to support them.

```
exec rainbows '66,97,25'   --testing



create PROC rainbows
    @ProjectIDs NVARCHAR(1000)      
AS      

DECLARE @ProjIDs TABLE (id INT)     
INSERT @ProjIDs  SELECT DISTINCT value FROM fn_Split(@ProjectIDs, ',')    

--get core data set
SELECT t1.ProjectID,t1.ProjectName,
       case sco.CID when 37 then 'BRS Start'
                    when 37 then 'BRS end'
                    when 39 then 'SRS'
                    when 41 then 'SAD'
                    when 45 then 'Product Profile Review'
                    when 47 then 'SE Integration'
                    when 50 then 'IDE'
                    when 53 then 'UAT'
                    when 72 then 'PE Testing'
                    when 73 then 'Code Freeze'
                    when 75 then 'Dark Pod'
                    when 77 then 'Production' end CID, 
       coalesce(t2.EndDate, t1.EndDate) MilestoneEndDate 
INTO #DATA    
FROM StatusCode sco    
      LEFT OUTER JOIN    
           (SELECT p.ProjectId,p.ProjectName,sc.CID,rs.EndDate
              FROM StatusCode sc    
             INNER JOIN ReleaseSchedule rs ON sc.CID = rs.MilestoneCID    
             INNER JOIN Project p  ON rs.ReleaseID = p.ReleaseID 
             INNER JOIN @ProjIDs pList ON p.ProjectId = pList.id
            ) AS t1 ON sco.CID = t1.CID    
      LEFT OUTER JOIN    
           (SELECT sc.CID, pm.EndDate
              FROM StatusCode sc    
             INNER JOIN ProjectMilestone pm ON sc.CID = pm.MilestoneCID 
             INNER JOIN @ProjIDs pList ON pm.ProjectId = pList.id
            ) AS t2 ON sco.CID = t2.CID   
WHERE sco.CID IN (37, 39, 41, 45, 47, 50, 53, 72, 73, 75, 77)    

select ProjectID,ProjectName,[BRS start],[BRS Start] [BRS end],[SRS],[SAD],[Product Profile Review],[SE Integration],[IDE],[UAT],
                                         [PE Testing],[Code Freeze],[Dark Pod],[Production]
 from (
SELECT * FROM  #DATA
PIVOT (MAX(MilestoneEndDate) FOR CID IN ([BRS start],[BRS end],[SRS],[SAD],[Product Profile Review],[SE Integration],[IDE],[UAT],
                                         [PE Testing],[Code Freeze],[Dark Pod],[Production]
)) AS P) t1
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
create PROC rainbows
    @ProjectIDs NVARCHAR(1000)      
AS      

DECLARE @ProjIDs TABLE (id INT)     
INSERT @ProjIDs  SELECT DISTINCT value FROM fn_Split(@ProjectIDs, ',')    

--get core data set
SELECT t1.ProjectID,t1.ProjectName,
       case sco.CID when 37 then 'BRS Start'
                    when 37 then 'BRS end'
                    when 39 then 'SRS'
                    when 41 then 'SAD'
                    when 45 then 'Product Profile Review'
                    when 47 then 'SE Integration'
                    when 50 then 'IDE'
                    when 53 then 'UAT'
                    when 72 then 'PE Testing'
                    when 73 then 'Code Freeze'
                    when 75 then 'Dark Pod'
                    when 77 then 'Production' end CID, 
       coalesce(t2.EndDate, t1.EndDate) MilestoneEndDate ,
       CASE WHEN sco.CID=37 then coalesce(t2.startDate, t1.startDate) else null as SRS_StartDate
INTO #DATA    
FROM StatusCode sco    
      LEFT OUTER JOIN    
           (SELECT p.ProjectId,p.ProjectName,sc.CID,rs.EndDate, rs.startDate
              FROM StatusCode sc    
             INNER JOIN ReleaseSchedule rs ON sc.CID = rs.MilestoneCID    
             INNER JOIN Project p  ON rs.ReleaseID = p.ReleaseID 
             INNER JOIN @ProjIDs pList ON p.ProjectId = pList.id
            ) AS t1 ON sco.CID = t1.CID    
      LEFT OUTER JOIN    
           (SELECT sc.CID, pm.EndDate, pm.startDate
              FROM StatusCode sc    
             INNER JOIN ProjectMilestone pm ON sc.CID = pm.MilestoneCID 
             INNER JOIN @ProjIDs pList ON pm.ProjectId = pList.id
            ) AS t2 ON sco.CID = t2.CID   
WHERE sco.CID IN (37, 39, 41, 45, 47, 50, 53, 72, 73, 75, 77)    

select ProjectID,ProjectName,SRS_StartDate,[BRS start],[BRS Start] [BRS end],[SRS],[SAD],[Product Profile Review],[SE Integration],[IDE],[UAT],
                                         [PE Testing],[Code Freeze],[Dark Pod],[Production]
 from (
SELECT * FROM  #DATA
PIVOT (MAX(MilestoneEndDate) FOR CID IN ([BRS start],[BRS end],[SRS],[SAD],[Product Profile Review],[SE Integration],[IDE],[UAT],
                                         [PE Testing],[Code Freeze],[Dark Pod],[Production]
)) AS P) t1
```

Comment: im getting a syntax error on the new line: CASE WHEN sco.CID=37 then coalesce(t2.startDate, t1.startDate) else null as SRS_StartDate

Comment: also, the result set doesn't return data pertaining to each of the projectIds. all the milestone end dates are dups. the dates for projectid=25 int he test data is different from the rest but the results of the proc have all the dates as the same.